# The output expected is "one" "four" "five" "zero" but i keep getting one four zero five;

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public class NumberToWords {

    public static void numberToWords(int number) {

        int lastdigit =0;
        int correctway=0;
```

//the original number got reversed here to make it right when printing the text

```
        int originalnumber=reverse(number);
```

//getting the number count using the getdigitcount method

```
        int numberCount = getDigitCount(number);
        int reverseCount = getDigitCount(originalnumber);
```

// if the input number ismall then 0 then a error is thorn
if ( originalnumber <  0) {

```
            System.out.println("Invalid Value");
```

//if the original number is just 0 then zero is outputted
}
else if (originalnumber ==0) {

```
            System.out.println("Zero");}
```

//in any other sceanario the while loop gets run

```
        else {
```

// so while the oriignal number is not = 0 this is run
while (originalnumber!=0) {

// here just getting the remainder after division by 10 which gives us the last digit

```
                lastdigit = originalnumber % 10;
```

//here i'm using a switch case to print the correct text with the correostponding lastdigit

```
                switch(lastdigit) {

                case 0: System.out.println("Zero");
                break;

                case 1: System.out.println("One");
                break;

                case 2: System.out.println("Two");
                break;

                case 3: System.out.println("Three");
                break;

                case 4: System.out.println("Four");
                break;

                case 5: System.out.println("Five");
                break;

                case 6 :System.out.println("Six");
                break;

                case 7: System.out.println("Seven");
                break;

                case 8: System.out.println("Eight");
                break;

                case 9: System.out.println("Nine");
                break;


                }
```

//as this is a while loop itwill run forever unless the condition set is false which will happen after the thing is = 0
originalnumber/=10;

//checking the count and adding zero to the scrren until both the counts become same

// i'm assuming the error is comming from here, and that it should be placed outside the while loop above just want someone to explain to me why that is the case
while (numberCount!=reverseCount){

```
                    System.out.println("Zero");

                    reverseCount++;
                }


            }

        }
    }


//wiritng a revirse method 
    public static int reverse(int x) {


        int finalreversed=0;
//times the number by 10 which moves the decimal to the right so we can add values to it 
        while(x!=0) {

            finalreversed = finalreversed * 10;
            finalreversed = finalreversed + x % 10;
            x/=10;


        }
        return finalreversed;


    }

    public static int getDigitCount(int number){

        if (number < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (number == 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        int count;
        for (  count =0; number >0; count ++) {

            number /=10;

        }
        return count;
    }


}
```

Comment: please add some paragraph that explains your code and your problem.

Comment: Your assumption (_"it should be placed outside the while loop above"_) is correct. That is because of the following: The only situation where the digit counts will differ after reversing the number is when there are one or more zeros at the end of your number. For example, `1450` becomes `541` (not `0541`). So you have to do this final `while (numberCount != reverseCount) {...}` at the end, also (after the main `while` loop. **Recommendation**: step through your code line by line in a debugger and you should see the problem more easily.

Comment: By the way, your approach is overly complicated (e.g. reversing the digits). Do you _have_ to do it that way? Otherwise, there are much simpler approaches.